# How to calculate time difference in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have to calculate date time difference, how to do that in PHP? I need exact hours, mins and secs. Anybody have the scripts for that?

Answer (score 31):

Use the [diff() method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) of PHP's [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/datetime) like this:-

```
$lastWeek = new DateTime('last thursday');
$now = new DateTime();
var_dump($now->diff($lastWeek, true));
```

This will give you a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/dateinterval) object:-

```
object(DateInterval)[48]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 2
  public 'h' => int 11
  public 'i' => int 34
  public 's' => int 41
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 2
```

Retrieving the values you want from that is trivial.

Answer (score 10):

This should work, just replace the times in the time diff with the time the task started and the current time or the time the task had ended. For a continuous counter the start time would be stored in a database, or for elapsed time for a task the end time would as well

```
function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime){
   // convert to unix timestamps
   $firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
   $lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);

   // perform subtraction to get the difference (in seconds) between times
   $timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

   // return the difference
   return $timeDiff;
}

//Usage :
$difference = timeDiff("2002-03-16 10:00:00",date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$years = abs(floor($difference / 31536000));
$days = abs(floor(($difference-($years * 31536000))/86400));
$hours = abs(floor(($difference-($years * 31536000)-($days * 86400))/3600));
$mins = abs(floor(($difference-($years * 31536000)-($days * 86400)-($hours * 3600))/60));#floor($difference / 60);
echo "<p>Time Passed: " . $years . " Years, " . $days . " Days, " . $hours . " Hours, " . $mins . " Minutes.</p>";
```

Answer (score 9):

Check this.. This should work

```
<?php

function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime)
{

// convert to unix timestamps
$firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
$lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);

// perform subtraction to get the difference (in seconds) between times
$timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

// return the difference
return $timeDiff;
}

//Usage :
echo timeDiff("2002-04-16 10:00:00","2002-03-16 18:56:32");

?>
```

Comment: Hi vimard thanks for your valuable replay. Actually I want to display the oldness of files like in facebook or orkut. they shows time, days, week, year based display.

Comment: so this solves your problem rite...

Comment: @Vimard he wanted (4 years ago) to see difference in days, weeks, years not seconds.

Comment: i don't understand, it give me 07:00:00 even both number is same ($firstTime and $lastTime)

Answer (score 2):

For something like that use the built int time() function.

- Store the value of `time();` something like `1274467343`
  which is the number of seconds scince
- When ever needed retrive the value
  and assign it to `$erlierTime`.
- Assign `time()` again to the latter
  stop time you would want, lets just
  call it `$latterTime`

So now you have something like `$erlierTime` and `$latterTime`.

No just do `$latterTime - $erlierTime` to get the difference in seconds and then do your divisions to get numb of minutes passed, num of hours passed etc.

---

In order for me or any one to give you a complete script you would need to tell us what your environment is like and what are you working with mysql, sqlite etc... also would need to know how that timer is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use your custom code, there are many built-in functions in php which can let you do it easily.
[Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

1. First convert any your dates from "Y-m-d H:i:s" format to Linux time-stamp using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.
2. Make your calculations and use [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) to get current time-stamp if applicable.
3. Convert you calculated time-stamp to dates using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your start datetime and endtime through strtotime.

after that substract the starttime from the end time.

after that pass that difference to date or time format that you needed...

so you will get the exact difference between two date.