# How to find out the time difference and added to the previous storedtime?

Tags: php

I have the two times like this 
`2010-08-09 11:16:06`
`2010-08-09 11:19:12`
I need to find out the time difference between these two dates and also I need to store difference between these two.For example here the difference is `00:03:02` And if the user again start the timer and stop it  for example the second starting time is 
`2010-08-09 11:21:06`
End time is `2010-08-09 11:22:12`
I need to add this into the previous timer like `00:03:02`+`00:01:06` and need  to display total duration is `00:04:08`.
Ps:It may be starting and end time difference in days.
How can I do this?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to calculate time difference in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920335/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-php) and a [couple others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=time+difference+php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Store the duration in seconds
- Use `strototime` to convert dates into timestamps
- Use `date` to convert timestamps into dates
- Calculate second differences by subtracting the timestamps
- Calculate offset timestamps by adding the second difference to their timestamps