# How to calculate hour two date difference in php?

Tags: php, laravel, date, codeigniter

I have a time column is like this: "19-01-2022 12:49:00" also I need to current time.

I want to calculate current time minues my time column value but my result must be hours.

For example 19-01-2022 12:49:00 -> its my time and if current time 19-01-2022 13:49:05 result is a 1

I want to write if condition (currentTime-timeColumn>24) or (currentTime-timeColumn>48) like this.

Comment: related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763476/how-do-i-find-the-hour-difference-between-two-dates-in-php

Comment: or this, which points to other related/duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920335/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You have a laravel tag and therefore I suggest using Carbon.

Example:

```
$dateOne = Carbon\Carbon::parse("19-01-2022 12:49:00");
$dateTwo =  Carbon\Carbon::parse("19-01-2022 13:49:00");

$dateTwo->diffInHours($dateOne); //gives you 1
```

Notes:
You do not need to parse into Carbon if the column name is already mutated through `$dates` array in the model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Carbon documentation for reference:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Hope this points you in the right direction.